# Finding Probabilities from moment generating functions

Tags: probability

> If
>
> $$M_X(t) = (1 - p + pe^t)^5,$$
>
> find $P(X \le 1.23).$

I seem not to understand the connection between cdf and mgf. Can I find the $E(X)$ and then use the formula for $E(X)$ to derive the probability? I am so confused.

Comment: No, but you could recognize that as a familiar MGF and then write down the pdf for the distribution it represents.

Comment: Do you know what p is? Are you sure it's not (1-p+pe^t)^5?

Comment: It have just corrected the question

Comment: The corrected question is much easier! Look up (or compute) the mgf of the binomial.

Answer (score 1):

We recognize $(1 - p + pe^t)^5$ as the moment generating function for a binomial random variable, so $ X \sim Binomial(5,p)$.

Since X takes on integer values, 
$$ P(X<1.23) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) = (1-p)^5+5p(1-p)^4$$

Comment: Thanks user51547, Since it is P( X < or = 1.23), shouldn't it be P(X=0)+P(X=1)+ P(X=2)?

Comment: $$2 \not\leq 1.23$$